# To worry about vs To be worried about - difference

Tags: differences, word-usage

Which one of the following is recommended to be used, and what is the difference between both of them?

> You do not have to worry about anything.

Or

> You do not have to be worried about anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first phrase has an active infinitive, and the second is a passive infinitive. They have virtually no differences in meaning (the one slight difference being that the first one implies that you *do not have to do something*, while the latter implies that you *do not have to have something done to you*), and they are completely interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

They're both perfectly acceptable and there's no difference in meaning between the two.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title, not just the sample sentences in the question, I would suggest:

> ... if you want to talk about a general, long-lasting worry, say *I worry about you*, and if you want to talk about a specific worry related to a specific event that’s happening now (or happened recently), you can
>   say *I'm worried about you*.

from [bbc learning english](http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/ask_about_english/pdfs/aae_08_s2_prog_6_worry_worried.pdf).